# Convert from RDF "type qualified literal" to Prolog atom in SWI Prolog

Tags: prolog, rdf, swi-prolog

The "SWI-Prolog Semantic Web Library 3.0" allows you to easily assert and query an RDF triple like this:

```
- rdf_assert(number, is, 1).
true.

?- rdf(number, is, X).
X = 1^^'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer'.
```

How can you convert X from the "type qualified literal" format (described [here](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=rdf/3)) to a standard Prolog atom: X = 1?

I found [xsdp_convert/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=xsdp_type%3Axsdp_convert/3) but it needs the type (`'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer'`) and the value (`1`) passed in as separate arguments. How do I break apart the "type qualified literal" (`1^^'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer'`) to do this?

Or better yet: does that `value^^type` format actually mean something in Prolog and allow for a more elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use unification, decompose the compound term that you get, or access its arguments:

```
?- use_module(library(semweb/rdf11)).
true.

?- rdf_assert(number, is, 1).
true.

?- rdf(number, is, N^^URI).
N = 1,
URI = 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer'.

?- rdf(number, is, X), X =.. List.
X = 1^^'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer',
List = [^^, 1, 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer'].

?- rdf(number, is, X), arg(1, X, N).
X = 1^^'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer',
N = 1.
```

Comment: Thanks for the options Paulo.  CapelliC's option is good additional data but since you answered first I'll mark this as the answer

Answer (score 1):

I think we can (should ?) use standard prefixes by means of the provided interfaces, instead of hardcoding them. So...

```erlang
?- rdf(S,P,O^^xsd:integer).
S = number,
P =  (is),
O = 1.

?- rdf(S,P,O),rdf_equal(O,N^^xsd:integer).
S = number,
P =  (is),
O = 1^^'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer',
N = 1.
```

SWI-Prolog strives for efficiency, and we should use the provided interfaces because [rdf_prefixes](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/semweb/rdf_prefixes.pl) get special handling from the term rewrite infrastructure, that is, literals are handled when compiling/loading source files.

To keep in mind: we can define our own applicative domain prefixes to benefit of the same treatment as standard defined ones.

Comment: Not sure I understand.  Are you just saying to use ^^xsd:integer instead of 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer' like Paulo did below?  Sure, that makes sense.  This doesn't give you any special way to convert a term of the form X^^Y into a Prolog atom using a helpful built in predicate does it?  That's what I'm looking for.

Comment: the key (I think) it's rdf_equal/2. The point being that RDF prefixes are subject to *term rewriting*, and SWI-Prolog has special machinery coupled to modules to allow for 'safe' prefixes usage. rdf_equal (not easy to spot in documentation) allows the rewriting take place...